# Asking the user to enter information to then output info using OOP

Tags: ruby

How do I have the user enter the radius of the Circle?

```
class Circle
  @@PI = 3.14

  def initialize
    @radius = 0
  end

  def set_radius radius
    @radius = radius
  end

  def area
    @radius * @radius * @@PI
  end
end

c = Circle.new
c.set_radius 5
puts c.area
```

I know that I will be using something with: `gets.chomp`.

Comment: Good luck trying to *avoid* using OOP with a Ruby program.

Comment: You don't actually need to have `@@PI` with the two `@@`. You could just make it a constant, `PI`, and then it'll always be `Circle::PI`. I think `@@` is really more for something that's mutable. And with that said, I've *never* used `@@`. I'm just aware of it is all.

Comment: @mohawkjohn, your advice is good, but PI is already a constant in the Math module, so why not just use that?

Comment: Well, yes, of course -- but it seemed that the OP was trying to understand the concepts involved in Ruby programming. I was discussing how to define constants. And you've already provided, as an answer, the method for using `Math::PI`, so I saw no reason to be redundant. =)

Comment: Makes sense! I've never used @@class_variables, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `c.set_radius 5` with `c.set_radius gets.to_i`.

Here are a few other changes I'd make, just to clean it up a bit:

```
class Circle
  def initialize(params = {})
    @radius = params[:radius]
  end

  def area
    @radius**2 * Math::PI
  end
end

puts "Please enter circle radius:"
puts Circle.new(radius: gets.to_i).area
```

Comment: I'd also add a `puts "Enter circle radius as an integer:"`

Comment: I included your suggestion along with some other refactoring above.  Thanks!